# jquery .text() not working on click

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make a togable anchor tag, till now achieved this I want it to toggle both fa icon and the text on click. so far fa icon toggles but cant toggle the text can anyone show me how to do it.

html

```
<h5 class="text-muted"> Education <a id="btnExp" class="fa fa-plus">ADD</a> </h5>
```

JS

```
$('h5 #btnExp').on('click', function () {
    $("h5 #btnExp").toggleClass("fa fa-minus fa fa-plus");
    $("#btnExp").text("123");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prevent its default action as element is anchor. Also wrap your code  in [document-ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('h5 #btnExp').on('click', function() {
    $("h5 #btnExp").toggleClass("fa fa-minus fa fa-plus");
    $(this).text($(this).text() === '123' ? 'ADD' : '123'); //Also toggle text
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h5 class="text-muted"> Education <a id="btnExp" class="fa fa-plus">ADD</a> </h5>
```

Comment: "Also wrap your code in document-ready handler" *if the script precedes the elements it references on the page* (general good advice, but best to qualify it) :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Is it possible to toggle this text aswell

Answer (score 3):

Change `$("#btnExp").text("123");` to `$(this).text("123");`

Comment: This is completely untrue. Anchors do have the `text()` property and there is no `innerHml` jQuery property (you meant `html()` or `("#btnExp")[0].innerHTML = "123"` anyway)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie can you explain, I'm open to critizism

Comment: Ermmm... See above (and Satpal's working answer). Anchors *do* have a `text()` property you can get and set. jQuery objects *do not* have an `innerHTML` method (they have `html()`)

Comment: I don't recall jQuery having `innerHtml` method and anchor element do have text property. Also html isn't same as text

Comment: @kidwon thanks for the update I will update the answer accordingly

Comment: I am not sure copying another user's answer over a completely wrong answer is appropriate... Best you simply delete it (or add something new, and of value, to it). :)

Comment: Your third answer is now more suited as a comment. As it is an `id` anyway (and therefore a unique *fast* lookup), your new code makes little difference to the actual problem at hand. Nice try though :)

Comment: :) ha ha ha thanks @TrueBlueAussie 

In which chat room can I Find you?